# How to reliably detect an Internet connection at Android phone wake up

Tags: java, android

I have an App that relies on Internet connection at startup, and I am able to detect that ok with the code below.

However when the phone has been idle for some time and I unlock it and start my app it does not find the connection immediately and I have to re-start the app again to get success.

I have tried waiting in a thread and retrying the code below again with no success too.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

**Code**

```
    // check Network/Internet connection
    public boolean isOnline() {

    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
                }
            }
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: call the method in onresume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in the `onResume()` of your activity. That way it'll be checked each time you return to the activity.

Additionally, add a flag to know whether to check for the connection, and set that flag to true in the `onPause()` of your activity. Reset it to false in your `onResume()`.

Something like:

```
boolean check;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle blah) {
      super(blah);
      check = true;
      // whatever else
    }

    protected void onResume() {
      if(check) {
        isOnline();
        // Everything else

        check = false;
      }
      super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
      check = true;
      super.onPause();
    }
```

**EDIT**: `onResume()` won't be called unless this activity is.. well being resumed, so you could just add:

```
protected void onResume() {
  isOnline();
  // Everything else
  super.onResume();
}
```

Look at this flow chart from the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for a better understanding:
[image]

Comment: Why the need for `check`, when will `onResume()` be called when `check` is false?

Comment: Not really. The OP wants to check each time the activity resumes, irrespective of whether isOnline() was true the last time.

Comment: @Sam If I travel from this activity to another and then back to this one. The OP just mentioned about checking after sleep, not moving between activities (in which case your suggestion stands)
**EDIT:** Darn, just thought 'bout it. Good point, check might be pointless.